# Strange imperative onScroll routing behavior in Next.js (only rendering on server)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, isomorphic-javascript, next.js

I am trying to use Next.js imperative routing api in a scroll handler for page navigation. When I attach to window, it is very nearly perfect, with the small exception that there is a color 'flash' as scroll position resets (need to continue to scroll up from bottom of new route if navigated to through top of previous page, and the color transition needs to be seamless, which doesn't seem possible because of the browser's milliseconds with scrollTop at 0). Code:

```js
export default class ScrollOMatic extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      prevRoute: '',
      nextRoute: '',
      isEndOfScroll: false
    }
    binder(this, ['handleScroll'])
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      console.log(window)
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
    const {
      prevRoute,
      nextRoute
    } = this.props.routeData
    this.setState({
      prevRoute,
      nextRoute
    })
    Router.prefetch('us')
    Router.prefetch('work')
    Router.prefetch('services')
    Router.prefetch('converse')
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  }
  handleScroll(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let {
      scrollTop,
      scrollHeight
    } = e.srcElement.scrollingElement
    scrollHeight = scrollHeight / 2
    const scrollTiplier = scrollTop / scrollHeight
    if (scrollTop === 0) {
      Router.push(this.state.prevRoute)
      window.scrollTo(0, scrollHeight - 1, {
        duration: 0
      })
    }
    if (scrollTiplier === 1) {
      Router.push(this.state.nextRoute)
      window.scrollTo(0, 1, {
        duration: 0
      })
    }
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className = 'scroll-o-matic' >{ this.props.children }</div>
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

So, I'm using a container with its own scroll behavior, inspired by react-horizontal-scroll which seems promising. But a strange thing happens with this new code. The new route is rendered client-side for just a moment, and the page refreshes as the new route is fetched from the server. See gif and code:
[image]

```js
// inspired by react-horizontal-scroll
import { Motion, spring, presets } from 'react-motion'
import raf from 'raf'
import Router from 'next/router'
import { fadeColor, binder } from '../../lib/_utils'
import { setScrollState } from '../../lib/_navRules'

export default class ScrollOMatic extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      prevRoute: '',
      nextRoute: '',
      animValues: 0
    }
    binder(this, ['handleWheel', 'resetMin', 'resetMax', 'navigator', 'canIscroll', 'getLayoutData'])
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    const { prevRoute, nextRoute } = this.props.routeData
    this.setState({
      prevRoute,
      nextRoute
    })

    const prevRouteName = prevRoute === '/' ? 'index' : prevRoute.replace('/', '')
    const nextRouteName = prevRoute === '/' ? 'index' : nextRoute.replace('/', '')
    Router.prefetch(prevRouteName)
    Router.prefetch(nextRouteName)
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    if (this.props.children !== nextProps.children) { this.resetMin() }
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
    if (true &&
      this.calculate.timer !== void 0 &&
      this.props.children === nextProps.children &&
      this.state.animValues === nextState.animValues) {
      return false
    }
    if (true &&
      this.props.children === nextProps.children &&
      this.canIscroll() === false) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }

  componentDidUpdate () { this.calculate() }

  getLayoutData () {
    const scrollOMatic = DOM.findDOMNode(this.scrollOMatic)
    const scrollTray = DOM.findDOMNode(this.scrollTray)
    const max = scrollOMatic.scrollHeight
    const win = scrollOMatic.offsetHeight
    const currentVal = this.state.animValues
    const bounds = -(max - win)
    const trayTop = scrollTray.offsetTop
    const trayOffsetHeight = scrollTray.offsetHeight
    const trayScrollHeight = scrollTray.scrollHeight
    const scrollOMaticRect = scrollOMatic.getBoundingClientRect()
    const scrollOMaticTop = scrollOMaticRect.top
    const scrollOMaticHeight = scrollOMaticRect.height
    const scrollOMaticOffsetHeight = scrollOMatic.offsetHeight
    return {
      currentVal,
      bounds,
      scrollTray,
      trayTop,
      trayOffsetHeight,
      trayScrollHeight,
      scrollOMatic,
      scrollOMaticTop,
      scrollOMaticHeight,
      scrollOMaticOffsetHeight,
      scrollOMaticRect
    }
  }

  calculate () {
    const layout = this.getLayoutData()
    clearTimeout(this.calculate.timer)
    this.calculate.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      const max = layout.trayScrollHeight
      const win = layout.scrollOMaticOffsetHeight
      const currentVal = this.state.animValues
      const bounds = -(max - win)
      if (currentVal >= 1) {
        this.resetMin()
      } else if (currentVal <= bounds) {
        const x = bounds + 1
        this.resetMax(x)
      }
    })
  }

  resetMin () { this.setState({ animValues: 0 }) }
  resetMax (x) { this.setState({ animValues: x }) }

  canIscroll () {
    const layout = this.getLayoutData()
    return layout.trayOffsetTop < layout.scrollOMaticTop ||
      layout.trayOffsetHeight > layout.scrollOMaticHeight
  }

  handleWheel (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const rawData = e.deltaY ? e.deltaY : e.deltaX
    const mouseY = Math.floor(rawData)
    const animationVal = this.state.animValues
    const newAnimationVal = (animationVal + mouseY)
    const newAnimationValNeg = (animationVal - mouseY)

    if (!this.canIscroll()) return

    const layout = this.getLayoutData()
    const { currentVal, scrollOMaticHeight, trayScrollHeight } = layout
    const isEndOfPage = -(currentVal - scrollOMaticHeight) + 1 === trayScrollHeight

    this.navigator()

    const scrolling = () => {
      this.state.scrollInverted
        ? this.setState({ animValues: newAnimationValNeg })
        : this.setState({ animValues: newAnimationVal })
    }
    raf(scrolling)
  }
  
  navigator () {
    const layout = this.getLayoutData()
    const { currentVal, scrollOMaticHeight, trayScrollHeight } = layout
    const shouldBeNextRoute = -(currentVal - scrollOMaticHeight) + 1 >= trayScrollHeight
    // const shouldBePrevRoute = this.state.animValues < 0

    if (shouldBeNextRoute) {
      Router.push(this.state.nextRoute)
    }
    // if (shouldBePrevRoute) {
    //   Router.push(this.state.prevRoute)      
    // }
  }

  render () {
    const springConfig = presets.noWobble
    return (
      <div style={{ position: 'relative', width: '100vw', height: '100vh' }} className='scroll-o-matic' onWheel={this.handleWheel}
        ref={scrollOMatic => { this.scrollOMatic = scrollOMatic }}>
        <Motion style={{ z: spring(this.state.animValues, springConfig) }}>
          { ({ z }) => (
            <div className='scroll-tray' ref={(scrollTray) => { this.scrollTray = scrollTray }}
              style={{
                height: '300vh',
                width: '100vw',
                // top: '-100vh',
                transform: `translate3d(0,${z.toFixed(3)}px,0)`,
                willChange: 'transform',
                display: 'inline-flex',
                position: 'absolute'
              }}>
              { this.props.children }
            </div>
          )}
        </Motion>
        <style jsx>{`
          .scroll-o-matic {
            background-color: ${this.state.currentColor};
          }
        `}</style>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

server code:

```js
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express()
    server.use('/static', express.static('static'))

    server.get('/', (req, res) => {
      return app.render(req, res, '/', req.query)
    })
    server.get('/us', (req, res) => {
      return app.render(req, res, '/us', req.query)
    })
    server.get('/work', (req, res) => {
      return app.render(req, res, '/work', req.query)
    })
    server.get('/services', (req, res) => {
      return app.render(req, res, '/services', req.query)
    })
    server.get('/converse', (req, res) => {
      return app.render(req, res, '/converse', req.query)
    })

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res, '/', req.query)
    })

    server.listen(port, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
  })
```

Maybe I don't understand Next's 'prefetch', but it definitely doesn't seem to be prefetching anything. I mainly am confused why a server-side page load is happening. Even using a wildcard request handler in express, the page reloads (but redirects to itself?), so it's not an issue with the server configuration I don't think.

What am I missing, oracles of the internet?

Answer (score 2):

The prefetch options is downloading the JS code of the page in background, so when you want to do a page change it's already downloaded, but nothing more, if you expect it to prefetch the already rendered HTML or the data you need to manually implement that.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have the same problem, obscure as it is, the issue wound up being related to Next's 'Styled JSX' rendering methods.

Apparently, even in client-side page loads, there's a half-second or so moment in which Styled JSX needs to load, for some reason. Which you normally don't notice, unless something as dramatic as background-color of the entire app is inside your ``` <style jsx>{``}<style> ``` tag. Putting all styles inside a regular old html style attr solved the 'flash'.

Answer (score 0):

scroll event wasn't firing. since my body was scrolling instead of documentElement.

I just removed height: 100% from my body tag and then scroll event started firing.

```
//in your CSS don't set height to percent
div{
    height: 100%
}
```